# Expanding code in etoolbox's \ifblank

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I am trying to use the etoolbox `\ifblank` (and its cousin `\notblank`), but I want to expand any macros in its test statement.  For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{longformt}
\newcommand{\longform}{\toggletrue{longformt}}
\newcommand{\iflong}[2]{\iftoggle{longformt}{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\quoteifnotblank}[1]{%
    \notblank{#1}{``#1''}{}%
}

% Try commenting this line.
\longform

This should be completely blank if the form is short:
\quoteifnotblank{\iflong{Some long quoted text}{}}

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that `\notblank` sees its argument of `\iflong{Some long quoted text}{}` as a string, not as code to be expanded, so the quotes always appear.  How do I expand arguments before they are passed to `\notblank`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\notblank` does no expansion to its argument, so you have to do it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{longformt}
\newcommand{\longform}{\toggletrue{longformt}}
\newcommand{\iflong}[2]{\iftoggle{longformt}{#1}{#2}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\quoteifnotblank}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\@tempa}{``#1''}{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This should be completely blank if the form is short:
\quoteifnotblank{\iflong{Some long quoted text}{}}

\longform

This should be completely blank if the form is short:
\quoteifnotblank{\iflong{Some long quoted text}{}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  What exactly is going on here?  I've never used `\expandafter`.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty We fully expand the argument saving what results in `\@tempa`; but, as I said, `\notblank` does not expand its argument, so we do it before it enters into action; the first `\expandafter` jumps over `\notblank` and makes the second `\expandafter` jump over the brace to finally expand `\@tempa`.

Comment: Hmm, I think I see.  Why not just use `\expandafter\notblank\expandafter{#1}` directly?  Won't `\expandafter` expand the `#1`?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty Only _exactly once_, so you'll get the meaning of the first token in `#1` (the definition of `\iflong`).