# Problem with \iftoggle and \notblank

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I'm having a problem passing parameters through `\iftoggle` to a `\newcommand` using `\notblank` inside; it's much easier to explain by showing a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \notblank{#1}{Value: '#1'}{EMPTY OR BLANK}
}

\begin{document}

\newtoggle{flag}
\togglefalse{flag}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \mycommand{A}
  \item \mycommand{}
  \item \mycommand{ }
  \item \mycommand{\iftoggle{flag}{X}{}}
  \item \mycommand{\iftoggle{flag}{X}{ }}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

This prints:

[image: outcome of latex code]

while I expected `EMPTY OR BLANK` string also for list items 4 and 5.

What's wrong with my approach?

---

**EDIT:**

It's already been answered in another [simliar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269498/expanding-code-in-etoolboxs-ifblank), anyway here's a solution for this specific case.

We should change `mycommand` as follows:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \protected@edef\@tmpa{#1}%
  \expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\@tmpa}{Value: '#1'}{EMPTY OR BLANK}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The argument to `\mycommand` is not blank in the final items. I think this has already shown up on the site.

Comment: @egreg: I thought it had something to do with expansion, but I couldn't find a solution by myself (neither a similar question here). Many thanks !