# Check if the text of a label is empty

Tags: etoolbox, nameref

I'm trying to check if a text label is empty. For this purpose, I tried to use the `\ifblank` command from the etoolbox package.
On the following MWE, I would expect that `\refdescx{\nameref{lab2}}` would return the text "EMPTY":

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refdescx}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\@tempa}{EMPTY}{NOT EMPTY'}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}
\label{lab1}

\section{}
\label{lab2}

\section{Third section}
\label{lab3}

References:  ``\ref{lab1}'' ``\ref{lab2}''\newline
Names:  ``\nameref{lab1}'' ``\nameref{lab2}''\newline
Check empty: ``\refdescx{\nameref{lab1}}'' ``\refdescx{\nameref{lab2}}''
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: I took inspiration from the following answer for my MWE: [https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269499/290212](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269499/290212)

Comment: @campa If I understand properly, one solution would be to define a command equivalent to `\nameref` but expandable I'm not sure if it is possible.
In the user documentation of `\nameref`, there is the mention that it is based on `\gettitlestring`. But I'm afraid that `\gettitlestring` might be as well not expandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically reference commands are not expandable: they want to issue a message if a reference is unknown, and hyperref wants to add links.
You can use the package refcount, it allows to retrieve the values in an expandable way:

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref,refcount}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\refdescx}[1]{%
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\@tempa}{EMPTY}{NOT EMPTY'}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}

\section{First section}
\label{lab1}

\section{}
\label{lab2}

\section{Third section}
\label{lab3}

References:  ``\ref{lab1}'' ``\ref{lab2}''\newline
Names:  ``\nameref{lab1}'' ``\nameref{lab2}''\newline
Check empty: ``\refdescx{\getrefbykeydefault{lab1}{name}{}}'' ``\refdescx{\getrefbykeydefault{lab2}{name}{}}''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was too slow. :-) Also, I'm not sure if that's a problem for the OP, but testing emptiness of the label name is bound to be unreliable, since typically (except for sectioning and captions, etc.), you'll get a stray `\@currentlabelname` from the last section.